# What is the command to just slightly increase the text height of a particular page?

Tags: macros, page-breaking

There is a command for just slightly increasing the text height of a particular page, something like `stretchthispage` or so. I know where it is in the LaTeX guide that I have at home, but I'm at work right now so I don't have access to it and I'm having difficulties googling for it.

Anyone who knows it of the top of their heads? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `\enlargethispage{<length>}` on the page in question, where `<length>` is usually a multiple of `\baselineskip` (the distance between two lines), e.g. `2\baselineskip`.

Comment: _THAT's_ it! Thank you very much for the speedy answer! =)

Answer (score 3):

two choices, e.g.:

at top of the page write: `\vspace*{-2cm}` to shift up the start line
anywhere in the page write; `\enlargethispage{2cm}` for more space at the bottom

instead of 2cm it makes sense to use multiples of `\normalbaselineskip`

If you are alread using package `geometry` you can also try `\newgeometry{...}` for
a new page layout.