# Pagebreak problem (stop my document from not pagebreaking)

Tags: tables, page-breaking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the command to just slightly increase the text height of a particular page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25723/what-is-the-command-to-just-slightly-increase-the-text-height-of-a-particular-pa)
>   [Squeeze some more lines on the current page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32112/squeeze-some-more-lines-on-the-current-page)

How would I shift up my text from the 2nd page to the 1st page? I realised if I removed a few lines from my personal summary (first section), the page will fit nicely.

But right now there is a big gap in my first page, how would I push up my 2nd page to my 1st page?

Edit: If you can't see the picture, i think if you right-click and find the image location, you can see the full picture.

My latex code is below.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{array, xcolor, lipsum, bibentry}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{scrbase,scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings} % pagestyle with page number
\lohead{John Doe}



\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.8}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedleft}p{0.14\textwidth}}
\newcolumntype{R}{p{0.8\textwidth}}
\newcommand\VRule{\color{lightgray}\vrule width 0.5pt}


\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}\Huge John Doe \end{center}
\vspace{1em}
\begin{minipage}[ht]{0.70\textwidth}
Address\\
Address\\
Address\\
Address\\
Address
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[ht]{0.48\textwidth}
Mobile: 12345\\
Email: 123@gmail.com\\
Date of Birth: 01/01/2012\\
Citizenship: World
\end{minipage}
\vspace{2pt}

\section*{Personal Summary}
Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. 

\section*{Education}
\begin{tabular}{L!{\VRule}R}
2009--2012&MSc Course.\vspace{5pt}\\
2006--2008& BSc Course.\\
\end{tabular}

\section*{Employment}
\begin{tabular}{L!{\VRule}R}
2011--2011&{\bf Name of company} Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here.  \\
&\begin{itemize}
\item Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. 
\item Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. 
\item Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here.
\item Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. 
\end{itemize}\\
\end{tabular}

\section*{Organisational Experience}
\begin{tabular}{L!{\VRule}R}
2011& Add my text here. \vspace{5pt}\\
\end{tabular}

\section*{Awards and Achievements}
\begin{tabular}{L!{\VRule}R}
2011&Add my text here. .\vspace{5pt}\\
2010&Add my text here. .\vspace{5pt}\\
2008&Add my text here. \\
\end{tabular}

\section*{Languages}
English, This, That.

\section*{Computer Skills and Competencies}
Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. 

\section*{Referees}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.65\textwidth}
\textbf{Name}\\
\textit{Title}\\
Address\\
Address\\
Address\\
Address\\
Contact no.: 12345678
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
\textbf{Name}\\
\textit{Title}\\
Address\\
Address\\
Address\\
Address\\
Address\\
Address\\
Address\\
Contact no.: 12345678
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! Although it works, is there anyway to automatically make my document stop pagebreaking like above? Ideally I'd like the section "Employment" to start on 1st page and just continue on in the 2nd page.

Comment: @Gary That's a bit hard considering the way you built your document, because all the sections are made up from stuff which doesn't break. Try to replace `tabular` by `longtable`.

Comment: Still, even longtable will not break inside an itemized list which is in a table cell. You need a completely different document structure. You should re-formulate your question to make this clearer.

Comment: Thanks, considering what you said, I think at the moment I'll just use \enlargethispage{2\baselineskip}. In the future I'll try a different document structure. Any different document structures to recommend?

Comment: @Gary Can be tricky because of the itemize inside a tabular structure. `mdframed` maybe? But I have no experience with it.

Comment: @StephanLehmke Thanks, I'll do more research into that in the future, might need to change the way I present the document in the future (maybe getting rid of itemize, not using tabular structure etc.)

Answer (score 0):

The only way to solve this is to break the tables manually like:

```
\section*{Employment}
\begin{tabular}{L!{\VRule}R}
2011--2011&{\bf Name of company} Add my text here. Add my text here.
Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text
here. Add my text here. \\
&\begin{itemize}
\item Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my
  text here. Add my text here. Add my text here.
\item Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my
  text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here.
  Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text
  here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my
  text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here.
\end{itemize}
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{L!{\VRule}R}
&\begin{itemize}
\item Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my
  text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here.
  Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text
  here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my
  text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here.
  Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text
  here. Add my text here. Add my text here.
\item Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my text here. Add my
  text here. Add my text here. Add my text here.
\end{itemize}\\
\end{tabular}
```